# SQL query on two task lists in Access - how to get the correct “Assigned to”?

Tags: sql, ms-access, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, ms-access-2010

As you all probably know, a Sharepoint task list has an "Assigned To" column. When I import a task list in Access, I get a table for the list and another table, "UserInfo" with the users for that list (those are the same users listed under Permissions for that list in Sharepoint). This UserInfo table has data such as the user's id, title, account, email, department and so on.

When I run the following query:

SELECT *

FROM FirstList

UNION ALL

SELECT *

FROM SecondList;

The "Assigned To" field changes to the ID of the person from UserInfo. Their name is under the "Title" field of the UserInfo table.

How should I modify the SQL query to place the title in the "Assigned To" column?

EDIT: here is an example

In FirstList I have a row with the following values: "Do this" "John Doe" "Not Started" corresponding to the "Title",  "Assigned To" and "Status" columns. In UserInfo I have a row with "30" "John Doe" "f2rdf" as values for "ID", "Title" and "Account".

After I do the union, instead of John Doe I would see the value 30. So how do I specify that I want to see the value of the title, not the value of the ID? Something like [Assigned To].Title? (which unfortunately doesn't work)

Answer (score 0):

A [Union](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_operations_%28SQL%29) query combines two like datasets. A requirement of a `Union` is that the number of columns are the same in both sets and that the datatype of each column of the first set matches the datatype of the matching column in the second dataset.

Based on your description of the problem it sounds like you are comparing two datasets that have the same number of columns with all of the same datatypes but with metadata in your second dataset that is out of order (or does not match) from your first dataset.

If you want your columns in your `FirstList` to match the columns in your `SecondList` then you will need to explicitly specify the order rather than relying on the `SELECT *` syntax. So in other words if the columns of your `FirstList` are `ColA, ColB, ColC` and the columns in your `SecondList` are `ColB, ColC, ColA` then you would want to change your query to read:

```
SELECT ColA, ColB, ColC
FROM FirstList
UNION ALL
SELECT ColA, ColB, ColC
FROM SecondList;
```

Otherwise (assuming the datatypes are all the same), you could end up having `ColB` data falling under your `ColA` column, `ColC` data in your `ColB`, etc....

Comment: No, you misunderstood my question: suppose ColB is the Assigned To column. The Assigned To column is getting its values from the UserInfo table. When I look in the FirstList table, I can see the names within the "Assigned To" column. However, after the union, I see the IDs of those names.

Comment: I made an edit to my question with an example, to be more clear.

Comment: I think maybe you misunderstand how a union works... A union combines the row results from one set with the row results from the second set and uses the same metadata structure that is defined in both sets. So based on your additional information, the query is working as intended. Are you looking more for a join? So that you want your SecondList to be shown as new columns as opposed to being listed within the same rows as FirstList?

Comment: Yes, I know how a union works. This isn't even about the SecondList. It's about the fact that after the union the contents of the "Assigned To" column are not the same as what they were in the original lists. In the original list it had data from the "Title" column of the "UserInfo" table. After, they had data from the "ID" column of "UserInfo".

Comment: In your example you only have a single column that matches between two sets. If you want only those combined then you should only pull in those fields by explicitly listing SELECT TITLE for both statements. The Union will only match first column with first column and second with second, etc... it cannot tell that your Column1 from your FirstList is the same column as Column2 from your SecondList. Just understand that by pulling in any additional fields beside your Title, you will not be able to avoid combining unlike data.

Comment: Except I'm not doing the union between FirstList and UserInfo, I'm doing the union between FirstList and SecondList. I think that's pretty clear from the SQL lines I wrote.